# Why doesn't nvrtc compiler emit this nvvm code fragments to ptx?

Tags: cuda, ptx

I have some NVVM code that I am trying to compile to PTX using nvrtc (i.e. using nvvmCompileProgram, nvvmGetCompiledResult).

Here is the nvvm code:

```
; ModuleID = 'test_warp_reduce'
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v16:16:16-v32:32:32-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-n16:32:64"
target triple = "nvptx64-unknown-cuda"

define ptx_kernel void @lambda_crit_4197([0 x float]* %_4200_4590, [0 x i64]* %_4201_4591, [0 x float]* %_4202_4592) {
acc_bidx:
  %0 = tail call ptx_device i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.tid.x()
  %1 = tail call ptx_device i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.ntid.x()
  %2 = tail call ptx_device i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.ctaid.x()
  %3 = mul nsw i32 %2, %1
  %4 = add nsw i32 %3, %0
  %5 = icmp slt i32 %4, 32
  br i1 %5, label %if_then12, label %next

if_then12:                                        ; preds = %acc_bidx
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds [0 x float]* %_4202_4592, i64 0, i32 %4
  %7 = load float* %6
  %8 = tail call i64 @clock()
  %9 = tail call float @reduce_step(float %7, i32 1, i32 31)
  %10 = tail call float @reduce_step(float %9, i32 2, i32 31)
  %11 = tail call float @reduce_step(float %10, i32 4, i32 31)
  %12 = tail call float @reduce_step(float %11, i32 8, i32 31)
  %13 = tail call float @reduce_step(float %12, i32 16, i32 31)
  %14 = tail call i64 @clock()
  %15 = getelementptr inbounds [0 x float]* %_4200_4590, i64 0, i32 %4
  %16 = getelementptr inbounds [0 x i64]* %_4201_4591, i64 0, i32 %0
  %17 = sub nsw i64 %14, %8
  store i64 %17, i64* %16
  store float %13, float* %15
  br label %next

next:                                             ; preds = %acc_bidx, %if_then12
  ret void
}

declare i64 @llvm.nvvm.texsurf.handle.p1i64(metadata, i64 addrspace(1)*)

; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone
declare ptx_device i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.tid.x()

; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone
declare ptx_device i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.ntid.x()

; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone
declare ptx_device i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.ctaid.x()

define i64 @clock() {
    %1 = call i64 asm "mov.u32 $0, %clock;", "=r" ()
    ret i64 %1
}

define float @reduce_step(float %a, i32 %b, i32 %c) {
    %1 = call float asm
     "{ .reg .pred p;
        .reg .f32 r0;
        shfl.down.b32 r0|p, $1, $2, $3;
        @p add.f32 r0, r0, $1;
        mov.f32 $0, r0;
     }", "=f, f, r, r" (float %a, i32 %b, i32 %c)

    ret float %1
}


!nvvmir.version = !{!0}
!nvvm.annotations = !{!1}

!0 = metadata !{i32 1, i32 2}
!1 = metadata !{void ([0 x float]*, [0 x i64]*, [0 x float]*)* @lambda_crit_4197, metadata !"kernel", i64 1}
```

And here is the generated ptx code:

```
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler
//
// Compiler Build ID: CL-19324574
// Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.27
// Based on LLVM 3.4svn
//

.version 4.2
.target sm_52
.address_size 64

        // .globl       lambda_crit_4197

.visible .entry lambda_crit_4197(
        .param .u64 lambda_crit_4197_param_0,
        .param .u64 lambda_crit_4197_param_1,
        .param .u64 lambda_crit_4197_param_2
)
{
        .reg .pred      %p<2>;
        .reg .f32       %f<11>;
        .reg .s32       %r<15>;
        .reg .s64       %rd<13>;


        ld.param.u64    %rd1, [lambda_crit_4197_param_0];
        ld.param.u64    %rd2, [lambda_crit_4197_param_1];
        ld.param.u64    %rd3, [lambda_crit_4197_param_2];
        mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;
        mov.u32         %r3, %ctaid.x;
        mov.u32         %r4, %ntid.x;
        mad.lo.s32      %r2, %r3, %r4, %r1;
        setp.gt.s32     %p1, %r2, 31;
        @%p1 bra        BB0_2;

        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd4, %rd3;
        mul.wide.s32    %rd5, %r2, 4;
        add.s64         %rd6, %rd4, %rd5;
        ld.global.f32   %f2, [%rd6];
        mov.u32         %r5, 1;
        mov.u32         %r14, 31;
        // inline asm
        { .reg .pred p;
        .reg .f32 r0;
        shfl.down.b32 r0|p, %f2, %r5, %r14;
        @p add.f32 r0, r0, %f2;
        mov.f32 %f1, r0;
     }
        // inline asm
        mov.u32         %r7, 2;
        // inline asm
        { .reg .pred p;
        .reg .f32 r0;
        shfl.down.b32 r0|p, %f1, %r7, %r14;
        @p add.f32 r0, r0, %f1;
        mov.f32 %f3, r0;
     }
        // inline asm
        mov.u32         %r9, 4;
        // inline asm
        { .reg .pred p;
        .reg .f32 r0;
        shfl.down.b32 r0|p, %f3, %r9, %r14;
        @p add.f32 r0, r0, %f3;
        mov.f32 %f5, r0;
     }
        // inline asm
        mov.u32         %r11, 8;
        // inline asm
        { .reg .pred p;
        .reg .f32 r0;
        shfl.down.b32 r0|p, %f5, %r11, %r14;
        @p add.f32 r0, r0, %f5;
        mov.f32 %f7, r0;
     }
        // inline asm
        mov.u32         %r13, 16;
        // inline asm
        { .reg .pred p;
        .reg .f32 r0;
        shfl.down.b32 r0|p, %f7, %r13, %r14;
        @p add.f32 r0, r0, %f7;
        mov.f32 %f9, r0;
     }
        // inline asm
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd7, %rd1;
        add.s64         %rd8, %rd7, %rd5;
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd9, %rd2;
        mul.wide.s32    %rd10, %r1, 8;
        add.s64         %rd11, %rd9, %rd10;
        mov.u64         %rd12, 0;
        st.global.u64   [%rd11], %rd12;
        st.global.f32   [%rd8], %f9;

BB0_2:
        ret;
}

        // .globl       clock
.visible .func  (.param .b64 func_retval0) clock(

)
{
        .reg .s32       %r<2>;
        .reg .s64       %rd<2>;


        // inline asm
        mov.u32 %r1, %clock;
        // inline asm
        cvt.u64.u32     %rd1, %r1;
        st.param.b64    [func_retval0+0], %rd1;
        ret;
}

        // .globl       reduce_step
.visible .func  (.param .b32 func_retval0) reduce_step(
        .param .b32 reduce_step_param_0,
        .param .b32 reduce_step_param_1,
        .param .b32 reduce_step_param_2
)
{
        .reg .f32       %f<3>;
        .reg .s32       %r<3>;


        ld.param.f32    %f2, [reduce_step_param_0];
        ld.param.u32    %r1, [reduce_step_param_1];
        ld.param.u32    %r2, [reduce_step_param_2];
        // inline asm
        { .reg .pred p;
        .reg .f32 r0;
        shfl.down.b32 r0|p, %f2, %r1, %r2;
        @p add.f32 r0, r0, %f2;
        mov.f32 %f1, r0;
     }
        // inline asm
        st.param.f32    [func_retval0+0], %f1;
        ret;
}
```

It seems that the nvvm compiler just eliminates code for mysterious reasons. For example, the calls for the clock function weren't emitted at all.

Whether I used the compiler optimization or not doesn't make a difference in the provided code.

Somebody told me that Cuda 7.5 had some similar issues (assembly not being emitted) on Windows. So I downgraded to 7.0. However, the problem is still in there.

Any clue why this might be the case?

Answer (score 2):

I can tell from experience that PTX code only calls builtin functions. User defined functions get inlined into the calling functions.

I can't seem to find the proper documentation for it right now, but I'll link it in when I find it.

In your code base there are many places code segments like this repeat:

```
    // inline asm
    mov.u32         %r7, 2;

    // inline asm
    { .reg .pred p;
    .reg .f32 r0;
    shfl.down.b32 r0|p, %f1, %r7, %r14;
    @p add.f32 r0, r0, %f1;
    mov.f32 %f3, r0;
    }
```

Does this look familiar ? The first line one is coming from clock, the second block is coming from reduce_step.

TL;DR: You don't see the calls because they got inlined.